# Passing Global variable in URL in Postman

Tags: javascript, postman

I have a `GET` request `/project/{project_id}`, `{project_id}` here is the ID created in other `POST` request which creates project.

My requirement is that once the ID is created in `POST` request (create project) response - that ID can be used in the URL of the `GET` request.

I have set the global `env` variable as

```
var jsonRespStore = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setGlobalVariable("id", jsonRespStore.id);
```

But how to use this variable in the URL?

Please help

Answer (score 2):

You can use a variable in a request by escaping it with double curl braces.

```
https://www.myhost.com/project/{{id}}
```

Comment: Further to this - Just use `pm.globals.set("id", pm.response.json().id)` to declare the variable.

Comment: You may need to accept Shaun's answer to close it out